# Tridion - compare function metadata issue upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP2 to Sites 9

Tags: upgrade, sites-9, metadata

When we compare Pages with metadata, we are getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to tridion stack exchange , please refer to this [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000005050) for related issue , please contact support if you need more details.

Comment: thanks for providing the details

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error is because the page metadata schema in your Tridion 2011 SP2 was modified at some point in time after it was created. If you check the history on that metadata, you'd find the *'creator'* metadata field removed at some point in time and *'metadata_title'* added later.

To fix this, you can use the CoreService API which has a `SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate()` function. This function synchronizes the metadata with its metadata schema. You'd have to pass the page TCM ID and the `SynchronizeOptions` as input. There are sufficient code examples of using this in StackExchange. First, try this on a test page before doing it for all pages.

C# syntax from the Content Manager Core Service API Reference Guide:

```
SynchronizationResult SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate(
    string itemId,
    SynchronizeOptions synchronizeOptions
)
```

Comment: thanks for providing the details